# Could I get banned for buying PSNow on my American PSNow Account and then playing the downloaded games on my Romanian account?

Tags: ps4, psn, ps-now

Would I risk to get banned? I live in Romania and my Romanian account is my main one. My American alt account has PSNow and I've been thinking about playing my PSNow games on my main account (Romanian). Note PSNow is not available in Romania so that would be suspicious. Anyone knows if it's bannable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to be banned.

You should read through [Terms of Service](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/network/legal/terms-of-service/), which are intentionally vague. Some quotes from this link will follow:

> PLAYSTATION™NOW CONTENT
>
> ...
>
> we offer interactive entertainment and gaming content through PlayStation Now ("PlayStation Now Content") to Account holders in select territories

And you are not in "selected territory".

> You may not manipulate or inflate usage of PSN Services.

This is part of code of conduct, it's vague, but your two accounts plan looks like manipulations for me.

They are going to watch you:

> We are not responsible for monitoring or recording any activity on PSN Services, including communications, although we reserve the right to do so.

And they definitely can ban you for anything (I omitted some words):

> If we determine that you ... have violated any term of this agreement ... we may take actions to protect our interests, including termination or suspension of your Account ...

Comment: Thanks, well, if I do get an email or something I'll just lie and tell them that I live in America and got my other account because I used to live in Romania.

Comment: @SaltyChipz your region could be found from your or your provider's IP address